# Calculate total number of row in a HTML form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form in which there is an ADD button(green plus symbol in the given form) used to adds row to the form using java script.After that this form is used to update the data in table.For updating the data in mysql table i have to run one loop  depending upon the number of row added by the user.
Problem is how to identify how many number of of times this loop will run. Presently I am manually inserting the value(Enter total number of item column is the given form) by one input box count.I want this value to be calculated automatically so that i can remove this input box.Someone suggested it to do with Ajax but I am not much aware about  Ajax.
the form looks like [image]
My code is-.

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
include('includes/config.php');
if(strlen($_SESSION['alogin'])==0)
    {   
header('location:index.php');
}
else{ 

if(isset($_POST['add']))
    {


$samplecount=$_POST["count"];

        for($i=0;$i<$samplecount;$i++){
            
$txntype="received";    
$orderno=$_POST['orderno'];
$orderdate=$_POST["orderdate"];
$stationerytype=$_POST['stationerytype'];
$stationeryqtyrecd=$_POST['stationeryqtyrecd'];
$sql="INSERT INTO  tblstationerystock(txntype,orderno,orderdate,stationerytype,stationeryqtyrecd) VALUES(:txntype,:orderno,:orderdate,:stationerytype,:stationeryqtyrecd)";

$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':txntype',$txntype,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':orderno',$orderno,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':orderdate',$orderdate,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':stationerytype',$stationerytype[$i],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':stationeryqtyrecd',$stationeryqtyrecd[$i],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$lastInsertId = $dbh->lastInsertId();

if($lastInsertId)

{
$_SESSION['msg']="Stationery Added successfully";

echo "<script>window.close();</script>";

}
else 
{
$_SESSION['error']="Something went wrong. Please try again";
header('location:index.php');
}
}
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        
                <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>Add Stationery Stock</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
                 
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <br />
        <div class="container" style="border: 2px solid #B22222;border-radius: 10px;margin-top: 25px;margin-bottom: 15px;>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <h4 align="center"><b><u>Add Stationery Stock<b></u></h4>
                    <br />
                    <form method="post" id="insert_form" onSubmit="if(!confirm('You have entered correct no of total items')){return false;}">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" name="orderno" class="form-control" placeholder="Order NO "/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="date" name="orderdate" class="form-control" placeholder="Date" />
                    </div>
                    &nbsp;
                    
                    <div>&nbsp;</div>
                    <h4 align="center"><b><u>Stationery Details<b></u></h4>
                    <div>&nbsp;</div>
                    
                        <div class="table-repsonsive">
                            <span id="error"></span>
                            <table class="table table-bordered"  id="tb">
                                <tr>
                                    <th  width=10%;>Sl.No.</th>
                                    <th width=45%;>Select Stationery Type</th>
                                    <th width=30%;>Enter Quantity</th>
                                    <th width=10%;><button type="button" align="center" name="add" id="addMore" class="btn btn-success btn-sm add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></th>
                                </tr>
                                
<tr>
<?php
for($i=1;$i<=1;$i++)
{   
?>

<td><input type="text"  name="slno" value= "<?php echo $i; ?>" class="form-control " readonly ></td>

<td><select  type="text" name="stationerytype[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Select Type" required >
   <option ></option>
   <option value="A4 GREEN REAM">A4 GREEN REAM</option>
   <option value="A4 WHITE REAM">A4 WHITE REAM</option>
   <option value="CELLOTAPE(BROWN)">CELLOTAPE(BROWN)</option>
     
     
</select></td>
<td><input type="NUMBER" name="stationeryqtyrecd[]" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" class="form-control" min=1 required ></td>


<td><a href='javascript:void(0);'  class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove" align="middle"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' align="middle"></span></a></td>
</tr>
<?php  }?>
</table>
                                <div class="block">
                                <input type="number" name="count" class="col-sm-2  glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="width: 70px ;height: 30px; color:red; margin-right:20px;font-weight: bold;" placeholder="&#xe093" max=15 min=1 required />
                                <label>Enter the Total Number of Items<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                                </div>
                                
                                
                                <div align="center">
                                <button type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-info" style="margin-bottom:20px"  align="middle" >ADD </button>
                                                            
                            
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>

<script>
var max = 14;
var count = 1;
<?php $abc = "<script>document.write(count)</script>"?>
$(function(){
    $('#addMore').on('click', function() {
            if(count <= max ){
              var data = $("#tb tr:eq(1)").clone(true).appendTo("#tb");
              data.find("input").val('');
               debugger;
              data.find("input")[0].value=++count;
              
            }else{
             alert("Sorry!! Can't add more than fifteen row at a time !!");
           }
              
     });
     $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
         var trIndex = $(this).closest("tr").index();
            if(trIndex>1) {
             $(this).closest("tr").remove();
              count--;
             
             // get all the rows in table except header.
             $('#tb tr:not(.tr-header)').each(function(){
             $(this).find('td:first-child input').val(this.rowIndex);
             })
           } else {
             alert("Sorry!! Can't remove first row!");
           }
      });
}); 
 
</script>
```

Comment: Loops are usually slow in SQL. You could generate an XML of all data and just update a joined version of that XML.

Comment: Declare a hidden variable with value as 0 or (total count in case of edit) while clicking on + button increment the hidden value,

Comment: @Lain May i request you to help me with that code.I am not aware about the XML

Comment: @Shibon But If i delete any row after click on +button  It will not calculate.Do you have any ided to Import the js varaible to php in this case

Comment: You have a `count` variable already. Change the type of the input `count` to `hidden` and update its value with your `count` variable on adding and removing.

Comment: What is the `count` variable doing? My guess is that it is keeping a count of the number of rows that are currently present in the form. You can use that variable. If not, then you can maintain a variable, that increments each time you press the `add` button.

Comment: @Developer Count variable is an input to the form .Here the user gives the total number of row.I want this to be removed .

Comment: In that case maintain a variable, say `numRows`, set its value to 0. Then each time a new row is added, update its value `numRows += 1`. Each time a row is deleted, update its value `numRows -= 1`.

Comment: @Developer Is this a variable in JS or in PHP

Comment: I am not familiar with PHP. But you can easily maintain this as a javascript variable.

Comment: @Developer Problem is with js variable.I have already a variable count  in js i want to export that value to PHP. I am not able to do that ,that is why i am inserting this value manually.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225458/discussion-between-roopa-and-developer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in php all fields passed in `$_POST` method using 
you can count number of `$_post` variable you get when form is submitted

if you have 4 files to insert in database with form
then you can count them by using `count($_POST)`
if there is 2 duplicate fields that you want to insert through loop you can execute loop for two time which means `count($_POST)/2`
but first of all you need to subtract the number of variables that are note related to database like submit button

```
$count=count($_POST);
$count=($count-1)/2   // subtract 1 for the submit post button
```

Comment: But the count value should be available at the first so that the loop will run.I could not get what you mean

Comment: How can i know there are four file

Comment: $count=count($_POST);
$count=($count-1)/2;  // where 1 is $_POST['submit'] and 2 is database table column (that is how many column in your database which you want to insert)